# Extjs - How to set label text by class

Tags: class, extjs, label

I would like to ask how can I set text to multi label with same class in controller? I have no problem with id but with class I can not find solution anywhere. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have used jQuery before? Even while this is possible in ExtJS it is not how I would recommend it in ExtJS.

You should use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('label[cls=YourClass]')`

Note: I assume that you applied the custom class via the cls property.